# creating externalregistration page in Identityserver3

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver3

I have identityserver3 service running great, the service is doing custom authentication and using angular pages to redirect for permissions, index, login and logoff pages as in IdentityServer3 example - CustomUser.

Now, I need to add external providers (say Google). I am not sure I completely understand how to redirect to "someexternalregistration" after google successfully authenticate to a page that would ask the user for userid of our system that will be associated with google login on all future calls.

so say the url for identity service is https://server/identity/login, https://server/identity/permissions etc.....

How do I map https://server/identity/someexternalregistration to html page?

Thank you
Mark

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer does this for you as long as your user triggers the link for the external IdP displayed on the login page. IdentityServer shows the links by querying the registered authentication middleware in the katana pipeline.